# how to create fat jar in android studio

Tags: android, android-studio, appium

```
public class WaitTests {

     WebDriver driver;

     @Before
     public void setUp() throws MalformedURLException {

      DesiredCapabilities capabilities = new DesiredCapabilities();

      capabilities.setCapability("deviceName", "XT1562");

      capabilities.setCapability(CapabilityType.BROWSER_NAME, "Android");

      capabilities.setCapability(CapabilityType.VERSION, "6.0.1");

      capabilities.setCapability("platformName", "Android");

      capabilities.setCapability("appPackage", "com.android.calculator2");

      capabilities.setCapability("appActivity", "com.android.calculator2.Calculator");

      driver = new RemoteWebDriver(new URL("http://127.0.0.1:4723/wd/hub"), capabilities);
      driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(15, TimeUnit.SECONDS);


     }

     @Test
     public void testFirstCalculator() {

      driver.findElements(By.xpath("//android.widget.Button")).get(0).click();

      driver.findElement(By.name("7")).click();

     driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(30,TimeUnit.SECONDS); 
    }
```

please any one tell me how to create fat jar in android studio (I am search in google but not getting any proper way for creating fat.jar ) so. I want to create executable file for run my above code. without any IDE

Comment: try for this library

Comment: https://github.com/musketyr/gradle-fatjar-plugin